# Receiving TCP Signals in Webapp Java application

Tags: java, web-applications, tcp, web, communication

Im currently developinga a webapplication which was developed by an colleague.Now I want to implement a TCP Interface. The aim to send a binary signal to the webapp (which is more like a website) and depending on that I want to change some appearance data of the website. The device which triggers the website can only send TCP Data.
As far as I have looked for a solution, there doesnt seem to be any way to send data via TCP to a webapp. Altough the webapp is running on localhost. There are many suggestions like websock, but I think this wont suit my case, since I want a TCP Communication. 
Perhaps there is a way using java function when developing the webapp and deploying it later?

Answer (score 0):

If your webbapp is deployed under some application server, e.g. Tomcat, you can register a `ContextListener` and get notified about your webapp's startup/shutdown. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) is a simple example for this.

To solve your particular case, you can open a TCP socket in `contextInitialized` method of your listener, handle connections&data as you wish and then you can close it cleanly in `contextDestroyed` method of your listener.